# Are provable quantum speed-ups possible for classes larger than NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, quantum-computing, query-complexity

In the oracle query model quantum computers can provably achieve a quadratic speed-up over any classical randomized computer [Grover, BBBV].

Are similar speed-ups provably possible for higher levels of the polynomial hiearchy or even PSPACE or EXP? (i.e. for classes that require single-exponentially many queries classically.)

Note, that I'm *not* asking for superpolynomial speed-ups. Quadratic is fine. Can I get quadratic speed-up e.g. for finding a satisfying assignment to some quantified formular $\forall x \exists y\; \varphi(x,y)$?

Note that for larger classes "scaling Grover up an exponential" to NEXP gives $2^{2^n}$ vs. $2^{2^{n-1}}$ queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't sure what you were asking in Rev 1 of the question, but in Rev 4 you've added a more precise question that I can answer:

> Can I get quadratic speed-up e.g. for finding a satisfying assignment to some quantified formular $\forall x \exists y\; \varphi(x,y)$?

Before that question can be answered, we have to make the model precise. We can think of Grover's algorithm as solving the following problem: $\exists x\; \varphi(x)$? 
In this model you only have access to $\varphi(\cdot)$ through an oracle who will evaluate it at any input you like.

So another way of thinking of the same problem is that Grover's algorithm evaluates the following formula: $\varphi(1) \vee \varphi(2) \vee \ldots \vee  \varphi(N)$. 
And this can be done in $O(\sqrt{N})$ queries, where it would need $N$ queries (deterministically) and $\Omega(N)$ (bounded-error) classically.

Similarly, $\forall x \exists y\; \varphi(x,y)$ can be written as a formula using only AND, OR and NOT over the variables $\varphi(i)$. In fact, it is a formula in which every variable appears exactly once (such formulas are called "read-once").

A very general result in quantum algorithms says that any read-once formula over the gate set {AND, OR, NOT} over $N$ variables can be evaluated in $O(\sqrt{N})$ queries. This result has a long history, beginning with generalizations of Grover's algorithm to handle bounded-error inputs, a breakthrough result of Farhi, Goldstone, and Gutmann ([Scott Aaronson's blog post](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=207)), a beautiful connection with span programs, an SDP characterization of quantum query complexity, etc.

The final $O(\sqrt{N})$ bound for any read-once formula over that gate set is from "Reichardt, B.: Reﬂections for quantum query algorithms. In: 22nd SODA. (2011) 560–569"

This almost answers the quantum part of your question, unless I've misunderstood it. However the classical query complexity of read-once formulas isn't well understood, so I can't tell you whether you always get a provable quadratic speed up or not.

Sometimes you do get a quadratic speedup, as in Grover's algorithm. If the formula is balanced and each gate has fanin 2, i.e., if it looks like $\forall x_1 \exists x_2 \forall x_3 \ldots \varphi(x_1, \ldots x_n)$, then the best classical algorithm, which happens to be a zero-error randomized algorithm, needs $O(N^{0.753})$ queries, so it's not really a quadratic speedup.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know. One more detail: is the number of quantifiers required to be constant or may it grow polynomially with the input? In other words, is it correct to interpret your answer as follows: quantum query algorithms can solve the PSPACE-complete QBF-SAT problem in O(N^0.5) queries, whereas any randomized needs O(N^0.753) queries.

Comment: @blk: The number of quantifiers need not be a constant, as in the last example where the final quantifier would be $\forall x_n$ or $\exists x_n$ depending on the parity of $n$. Your interpretation about QBF-SAT is correct if you interpret it as the query version of QBF-SAT, i.e., where you aren't given a formula $\varphi$, but must instead query a black box to get its output on any input.

Answer (score 6):

For total functions it is impossible to achieve more than a polynomial separation (i.e. $D(f) = O(Q^6(f))$) in the quantum query model, for more info see this [cstheory blog post](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2011/07/quantum-query-complexity/). With promise problems, you can have exponential seperations between the quantum and classical query complexity. However, classical query complexity is sometimes very deceptive in its correspondence to complexity classes; as are [partial functions in general](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7413/trade-off-between-time-and-query-complexity). If you don't allow promise problems, you can't get exponential separations and your relevance to the big classes is questionable. You can never expect more than an exponential seperation, because a quantum algorithm can be simulated by a classical computer with exponential overhead (actually, in PSPACE so looking above that is dubious).

Comment: I'm *not* asking for superpolynomial speed-ups. Quadratic is fine. Can I get quadratic speed-ups for finding a satisfying assignment to e.g. some for-all there-exists quantified formular?

Comment: @blk Grower's algorithm applies to anything that needs to be searched. So for each x search over y for an example, then with this nested search over all x for a counter-example... I don't think I understand your question anymore. Are you just asking when searching applies? Because anytime search is the best strategy you know, then you can use Grover's search to get a quadratic speed up.